# Battery not charging either detecting

Tags: 20.04, power-management, laptop, battery

So today,
I just noticed my battery wasn't charging and neither was detected I rebooted it several time but nothing worked.

Then I tried booting windows from Grub and when I did I was shown a light (battery signal light sided by charging socket) but still it was not charging though.

Colour of the light was red so that means it is not charging if it were to be then it mus lt blink (according to my laptop).

I loaded ubuntu back but no results so I booted windows again and when it was just almost booted the pc goes down as battery was very low.
Now I'm stuck I don't what do I do at this point.

I have lenevo ideapad

Please check it on urgent basis.

Comment: I don’t think this is anything to do with Ubuntu - there’s either a problem with the battery or its  charging (eg mobo / firmware / power cable). Battery charging isn’t handled by the OS.

Comment: 2 quick queries - (1) is the battery removable, (2) which ideapad model is it? There might be some advice we can give if you can provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like your battery is dead and its no fault of the OS you're running. If its a removable battery just order one and replace it or get help from a service center. Thnks!

Comment: Okay thanks for your support

Comment: @Arpan - do check (if you can) that it’s not a problem with charging (eg power supply) rather than the battery, before you shell out on a new battery.